# Openshift: build never ends

Tags: openshift, fabric8

I'm facing with a problem.

I'm performing:

```
mvn -Dfabric8.namespace=t-devhub-dev \
  -Dfabric8.openshift.trimImageInContainerSpec=true \
  -Dmaven.test.skip=true \
  clean package fabric8:resource fabric8:build
```

This process is hanging on waiting for `fabric8:build` ends:

```
[INFO] --- fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.38:build (default-cli) @ tdev-forum-service ---
[INFO] F8: Using OpenShift build with strategy Docker
[INFO] Copying files to /home/jcabre/projects/tdevhub/application-src/t-devhub/tdev-forum-service/target/docker/forum/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/build/maven
[INFO] Building tar: /home/jcabre/projects/tdevhub/application-src/t-devhub/tdev-forum-service/target/docker/forum/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/tmp/docker-build.tar
[INFO] F8: [forum:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]: Created docker source tar /home/jcabre/projects/tdevhub/application-src/t-devhub/tdev-forum-service/target/docker/forum/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/tmp/docker-build.tar
[INFO] F8: Updating BuildServiceConfig forum-s2i for Docker strategy
[INFO] F8: Adding to ImageStream forum
[INFO] F8: Starting Build forum-s2i
```

`docker-build.tar` is really straigforward:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── maven
│   └── tdev-forum-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
└── .s2i
    └── environment
```

where `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM docker.io/fabric8/java-jboss-openjdk8-jdk:1.2
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR=tdev-forum-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY maven /deployments/
```

and `.s2i/environment`:

```
JAVA_APP_JAR=tdev-forum-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Also, I've tried using `oc` client:

```
cat docker-build.tar | oc start-build --from-dir=- --loglevel=10 forum-s2i --follow
```

It's also handing on:

```
I0723 12:17:06.770656    3403 loader.go:357] Config loaded from file /home/jcabre/.kube/config
Uploading archive file from STDIN as binary input for the build ...
round_trippers.go:417] curl -k -v -XPOST  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: oc/v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a0ce1bc" -H "Authorization: Bearer cQFjgh_mjoAkbjYRhyz0sYCr8SaeauIpi4cjYL2UzDY" https://<cluster-url>/v1/namespaces/t-devhub-dev/buildconfigs/forum-s2i/instantiatebinary?name=forum-s2i&namespace=t-devhub-dev
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the build hasn't failed? Check the build status. Check the events for your project. When you have a build that seems to never finish like that it can be because it ran out of memory. There is usually an event indicating when a build is terminated due to running out of memory.

Comment: Could you take a look on [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin/issues/1333)?

Comment: I don't see that you have added anything from ``oc get events``.

Comment: I've just added this information at issue. Everything feels right, nevertheless.

Comment: I don't see output from ``oc get events`` on the issue. This is different information to events given by ``oc describe`` for build.